# Android: setting leftMargin property to a button automatically resizes it

Tags: android, margin

I have a simple button in my layout. Setting `leftMargin` to the view actually showing different results.

my_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/left_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="hello pandora"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In my activity, I'm setting the `leftMargin` property to the Button.

```
Button leftBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.left_btn);
LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) leftBtn.getLayoutParams();
params.leftMargin = 550;
```

If I set `leftMargin` as negative value or 0, its working fine, but If I set the value greater than the width of screen, it just resizing/compressing the button. I am expecting the button to go out of bounds like negative value.

[image]

I am expecting the button in the 3rd image to go out of bounds like the button in 1st image.
[image]

Please don't say to set the button `layout_alignParentRight="true"` in layout and `rightMargin = -50`in activity(this works) because I want to move the button from left to right.

Comment: What happens if you get the width of the button and override wrap_content programmatically with the actual width in dps? Another guess would be to set the parent views paddingRight to a negative value.

Comment: @Gyebro I have tried your your 1st solution, but it is actually removing the entire text 'pandora'. Please see my comment to the raj answer as it is showing same result. And for your 2nd solution, the position doesn't changes at all when setting paddingRight to a negative value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume assigning a specific width larger than the screen size (eg. 1000 dp) to the parent RelativeLayout should solve your problem.

Also why do you want to make out-of-screen UI elements? What is the desired behaviour? Perhaps a transition animation would be better?

**EDIT**

I've tried the animation + storing the measured width of the Button. It seems to work.
Can you try this on GB?

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

final Context context = this;
Button mButton;
int mButtonWidth; // Measured width of Button
int amountToMove; // Amount to move the button in the x direction

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    amountToMove = 600;

    mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    // Measure Button's width
    mButton.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    mButtonWidth = mButton.getMeasuredWidth();
    // Simple onClick listener showing a Toast
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context,"Hello Pandora clicked!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    // Onclick listener for the other button
    Button toggle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.toggle);
    toggle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Animate the other button
            TranslateAnimation a = new TranslateAnimation(0, amountToMove, 0, 0);
            a.setDuration(1000);
            // Finalize movement when animation ends
            a.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)mButton.getLayoutParams();
                    // Restore measured width and change left margin
                    lp.width = mButtonWidth;
                    lp.leftMargin = lp.leftMargin + amountToMove;
                    mButton.setLayoutParams(lp);
                    amountToMove = -amountToMove;
                }
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { /* Do nothing */ }
                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { /* Do nothing */ }
            });
            mButton.startAnimation(a);
        }
    });
}
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello Pandora"
    android:id="@+id/button" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Move the other button"
    android:id="@+id/toggle"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

**EDIT 2**

It works on a GB Emulator too (the Button gets clipped, is clickable).

[image]
[image]

Comment: Yeah translation animation is working perfectly. I just want to move the button from left to right out of screen. But i have no idea why marginLeft doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, I am sorry that translation animation got a problem now that the touch events are getting triggered all along the path of the animation in GingerBread (2.3v).

Comment: @DileepPerla I've edited my answer. Can you try this on GingerBread?

Comment: Hi sorry for my late answer. Actually its not working at all. I have already tried a similar approach. The problem is in `onAnimationEnd`, here when we translate the animation from 0 to `amountToMove`, at the end of animation, the leftMargin still remains 0 but the button has moved and when we increment the leftMargin in `onAnimationEnd`, it further moves, goes beyond the amountToMove. I'm getting all these problems in GingerBread only and ICS+ versions work fine.

Comment: My final understanding is, when we use `TranslateAnimation` to move, the button moves visually but the object remains at original position and so are the touch events. When we use leftMargin to move, the object also moves and touch events works perfectly, but the button size compress as shown in the ques. This is the problem in gingerBread only.

Comment: Did you measure the buttons metrical width and change the layoutparam's width from `wrap_content` to the measured value?

Comment: @DileepPerla I've tested on a 2.3.3 Emulator and the Button won't get compressed, it maintains its width. (see edited answer)

Comment: Got it now. Actually I am using RelativeLayout LayoutParams in my activity and that's the reason button gets compressed. If I change the LayoutParams to LinearLayout and root view in layout to LinearLayout it is working perfectly. But what if we need a RelativeLayout as root view in layout? FrameLayout or anything works as alternative to RelativeLayout?

Comment: You might try nesting the animated Button in a LinearLayout within your FrameLayout or RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

u can use max line=1 to show complete text in one line on button when you use leftMargin = 550;

try this

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/left_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="hello pandora"/>
```

Comment: It is working partially because `maxLines=1` just removing the extra lines, so the text "pandora" is completely removed and I am expecting something like "hello pand". It is currently displaying only "hello".

Answer (score 0):

Hello Edit your button property like this,

android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

android:singleLine="true"

and change parent layout to frameLayout

Comment: Nope,it just ellipsizing my text in the button, getting dots(..) at the end of button text.